# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: There is no currently active transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi, entity

I have Service with EntityManager and create DAO class in init method and pass EntityManager to DAO consctructor.:

```
@Slf4j
public class OPhoneService {
@Setter
    private EntityManager entityManager;

public void init() {
        log.info("init");
        log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        oPhoneDao = new OPhoneDaoImpl(entityManager);
        List<OPhone> oPhones = oPhoneDao.getAllOPhones(0);
        OPhone oPhone = oPhones.get(0);
        oPhone.setState(1);
        oPhoneDao.merge(oPhone);
}

}
```

and on this line `oPhoneDao.merge(oPhone);` get error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: There is no currently active transaction.
```

my merge method:

```
@Override
    public E merge(E e) {
        E merge = entityManager.merge(e);
        entityManager.flush();
        return merge;
    }
```

And my bean config

```
<bean id="oPhoneBean" class="....services.OPhoneService" init-method="init"
          scope="singleton">
        <jpa:context unitname="ophone" property="entityManager"/>
        <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start and commit transaction in your merge method.

```
@Override
public E merge(E e) {
    EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    E merge = entityManager.merge(e);
    tx.commit();
    entityManager.flush();
    return merge;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Aries blueprint. The transactional interceptor is not added to init methods.

See [ARIES-1715](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1715)

Comment: Ok. It is for test. I write this in init method becouse when I use quartz method I get some error. I create dao in init method and yhem try use this dao in schedulet quartz method and when I call merge my app Freezes

Comment: I'm happy that I quit and will not work with the karaf anymore.

Comment: Then why do you ask?

Comment: Because another 5 days should work with this curve system

Comment: Well I use karaf a lot and am quite happy with it.

Comment: I know) there are still 10 people who agree with you. In fact, we have used karaf 2.3.6 and have tried several times to change it to the latest version and continuously unsuccessfully. 2.3.6 karaf is the most terrible thing I've ever met. And you do not even have the proper documentation. I still have not found a normal example of how to make several modules and build a 4.1 carafe with these modules.

Comment: There is an example how to assemble a custom carafe 4.1 distribution, but there is no example how to create a bundle and add them to this distribution

Comment: I got some examples of how to create bundles and use them in a feature on http://www.liquid-reality.de. You then can add the feature to you custom distro. This is for example how I created a custom distro that includes the decanter features: https://github.com/cschneider/decanter-docker/blob/master/decanter-server/pom.xml

Comment: Where your modules? And custom futuries? This example show how create custom karaf and instal default bundles on startup and libs. But where in this examle how create custom bundle and add it to custom future?